# How do I make helm swoop not default the search to the word at point?

Tags: helm

When I trigger helm-swoop, it autofills the search with the word at point. For my most common use case, this isn't what I want. How do I disable it, so there's nothing in the search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When helm swoop starts up, it looks at the variable `helm-swoop-pre-input-function`. That variable stores a function that returns a string, and helm swoop uses that string as the default value. So, to not have anything in the search, make that value return an empty string:

```
(setq helm-swoop-pre-input-function (lambda () ""))
```

Its default value is to call `(thing-at-point 'symbol)`. There are more examples [here](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop#configure-pre-input-search-query). For example, to always use the previous search:

```
(setq helm-swoop-pre-input-function
      (lambda () (if (boundp 'helm-swoop-pattern)
                     helm-swoop-pattern
                     "")))
```